# Nuxt Js set value on each iteration v-for

Tags: vue.js, antd, nuxt.js

I have this code and I want to figure out a way to call `getPickedTeam` once every iteration and I know I cant set it every time to a data attribute because it will create an infinite re render loop.

The reason I want to set the PickedTeam is because I need to call it at least 5 times in the same iteration so it will be real slow if I find the team 5 times for 40 records.

```
        <span :key="match.id" v-if="matchViewable(match)" class="center-item">
          {{ getPickedTeam(record.resultMatches, match).pickedTeam }}
          <span v-if="match.mondayNight">
            &nbsp;<b>{{ getPickedTeam(record.resultMatches, match).pickedTeam }}</b>
          </span>
          //i'd like to call getPickedTeam here about 3 more times but it will become slow
        </span>
```

In my methods I have this

```
getPickedTeam(picks, match) {
      const team = picks.filter(function(pick) {
        return pick.match.id == match.id;
      })[0];
      if (team) {
        return team;
      }
    }
```

Maybe there is a way to set the getPickedTeam using vuex store but im a noob and I dont know how :(

Comment: This is one of those questions that's going to take someone about 30 minutes to pick apart, before the first follow-up question can even  be asked. I'd recommend rewriting this with a minimal working example in the fewest lines possible. Most of this template, and your exact data structure are not central to understanding of the underlying problem.

Comment: @DavidWeldon there

Comment: A better solution would probably be to use a computed property to generate a new data structure which exactly matches the needs of your template. I can't give an actual solution because I don't know what `picks` looks like.